# Sequel Migration update with a row's ID

Tags: ruby, migration, sequel

How can you run a Sequel migration that updates a newly added column with a value from the row?

The Sequel documentation shows how you can update the column with a static value:

`self[:artists].update(:location=>'Sacramento')`

What I need to do is update the new column with the value of the ID column:

something like:

```
self[:artists].each |artist| do
  artist.update(:location => artist[:id])
end
```

But the above doesn't work and I have been unable to figure out how to get it to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`artist` in your loop is a `Hash`, so you are calling `Hash#update`, which just updates the `Hash` instance, it doesn't modify the database.  That's why your loop doesn't appear to do anything.

I could explain how to make the loop work (using `all` instead of `each` and updating a dataset restricted to the matching primary key value), but since you are just assigning the value of one column to the value of another column for all rows, you can just do:

```
self[:artists].update(:location=>:id)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jeremy. Didn't realize I could just pass the column name as a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

if you need update all rows of a table, because it is a new column that need be populate

```
artists = DB[:artists]
artists.update(:column_name => 'new value')
```

or if you need, update only a unique row into your migration file you can:

```
artists = DB[:artists]
artists.where(:id => 1).update(:column_name1 => 'new value1', :column_name2 => "other")
```